# how can I use string.format() to right justify a string within three characters?

Tags: java, string

```
   | -1|  0|  1|  2|
   +---+---+---+---+
-2 | hi| hi| hi| hi|
   +---+---+---+---+
-1 | hi| hi| hi| hi|
   +---+---+---+---+
```

There is a chessboard with numberings on the first row and first column. Each cell can hold a string less than three characters and each string is right justified. So how can I use string.format() to right justify a string? Even though like "hi" is a two-character string, I still want a three-character cell, how can I make it? I am not very familiar with string.format()

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1):

To justify a String You can try this:

```
System.out.println( "%-3s %3s %n", NAME1, NAME2);
```

To get the left-justified column, a minus symbol, the number of characters,. So ''%-3s'' means 3 characters left-justified.

To get a right-justified column delete the minus sign.